# Where do i have to set the permission to have access to all placeholders tree in page editor?

Tags: sitecore

I am in the process of setting some security groups. 
For some page I do not have all the hierarchy of components/placeholders displayed.
What and where should I change in order to see full line of hierarchy?

I verified that the limited role has the write permission on those placeholders/components.. and still the users do not see the full tree.

thanks for any suggestions.

in images:
1. you can see the full tree of placeholders and components for the admin role below:
[image]

2. the limited role has the access only to the lowest 3 elements. Need to see full tree!
   [image]

thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

All set guys...

basically, you need to set the write access not only to the components, but also to all the placeholders in the hierarchy.  :).. logical right?

Thank you!